# unable to get the output of this code. Any help will be appriciated

Tags: python

```
def expenses():
    # Getting the cost of expenses from user "loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintainance."
    loanPayment = float(input('Enter monthly payment: $'))
    insurance = float(input('Enter monthly insurance: $'))
    gas = float(input('Enter monthly gas expanse: $'))
    oil = float(input('Enter monthly oil change expense: $'))
    tires = float(input('Enter monthly expense on tires: $'))
    maintenance = float(input('Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $'))

def monthlyCost(loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance):

    # Calculating and printing monthly expenses of automobile\
    totalMonthlyCost = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance
    print('Average monthly expense of automobile is', format(monthlyCost, '.2f'), sep='')
    yearlyCost(totalMonthlyCost)

def yearlyCost(monthly):
    yearlyExpense = monthly * 12
    print('Average yearly expense of automobile is $', format(yearlyExpense, '.2f'), sep='')
yearlyCost()

expenses()
```

Comment: There are many things missing here.  None of your functions returns anything at all, so there is never going to be any communication.  All of your functions are creating local variables, which are deleted when the function ends.  And even if you did save the results, you're calling `yearlyCost` before you call `expenses` to fetch the values.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your code:

First of all you need to call `monthlyCost()` at the end of `expenses()` using the new variables you created.

Second of all there is a typo in `monthlyCost()` where you use `monthlyCost` instead of `totalMonthlyCost`

Finally, you are calling `yearlyCost()` with no parameter, which you can simply remove beacause it will be called from `monthlyCost()`

I also added a ' $' to the end of the string in `monthlyCost()`

Try this:

```
def expenses():
    # Getting the cost of expenses from user "loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintainance."
    loanPayment = float(input('Enter monthly payment: $'))
    insurance = float(input('Enter monthly insurance: $'))
    gas = float(input('Enter monthly gas expanse: $'))
    oil = float(input('Enter monthly oil change expense: $'))
    tires = float(input('Enter monthly expense on tires: $'))
    maintenance = float(input('Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $'))
    monthlyCost(loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance)

def monthlyCost(loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance):
    # Calculating and printing monthly expenses of automobile\
    totalMonthlyCost = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance
    print('Average monthly expense of automobile is $', format(totalMonthlyCost, '.2f'), sep='')
    yearlyCost(totalMonthlyCost)

def yearlyCost(monthly):
    yearlyExpense = monthly * 12
    print('Average yearly expense of automobile is $', format(yearlyExpense, '.2f'), sep='')

expenses()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problems

1. Local variables. When you define variables inside a function, you'd expect to be using them later *within the function*. Otherwise, the values are not callable later on in your program unless you `return` them. Which leads to problem 2...
2. Nothing is returned from your functions. You can't call data from these later as a result.

### Solution

This should work.

```py
def expenses():
    # Getting the cost of expenses from user "loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintainance."
    loanPayment = float(input('Enter monthly payment: $'))
    insurance = float(input('Enter monthly insurance: $'))
    gas = float(input('Enter monthly gas expanse: $'))
    oil = float(input('Enter monthly oil change expense: $'))
    tires = float(input('Enter monthly expense on tires: $'))
    maintenance = float(input('Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $'))
    # Return a sum
    return loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance

def monthlyCost():
    # Calculating and printing monthly expenses of automobile\
    totalMonthlyCost = expenses()
    print(f'Average monthly expense of automobile is {totalMonthlyCost}.')

    # Return the statement as well in case you are printing it.
    return f'Average monthly expense of automobile is {totalMonthlyCost}.'

def yearlyCost():
    yearlyExpense = expenses() * 12
    print(f'Average yearly expense of automobile is ${yearlyExpense}.')

    # Return the statement as well in case you are printing it.
    return f'Average yearly expense of automobile is ${yearlyExpense}.'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yearlyCost()
```

#### Result

```
Enter monthly payment: $10
Enter monthly insurance: $10
Enter monthly gas expanse: $10
Enter monthly oil change expense: $10
Enter monthly expense on tires: $10
Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $10
Average yearly expense of automobile is $720.0.
```

### Efficiency

You can achieve the same result with just one function.

```py
def costs():
    # Getting the cost of expenses from user "loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintainance."
    loanPayment = float(input('Enter monthly payment: $'))
    insurance = float(input('Enter monthly insurance: $'))
    gas = float(input('Enter monthly gas expanse: $'))
    oil = float(input('Enter monthly oil change expense: $'))
    tires = float(input('Enter monthly expense on tires: $'))
    maintenance = float(input('Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $'))
    
    # Calculate sum
    total = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance

    ## Monthly Cost
    print('\n', f'Average monthly expense of automobile is ${total}.', '\n')

    ## Annual Cost
    print(f'Average yearly expense of automobile is ${total * 12}.')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    costs()
```

#### Result

This behaves like so:

```
Enter monthly payment: $15
Enter monthly insurance: $12
Enter monthly gas expanse: $13
Enter monthly oil change expense: $14
Enter monthly expense on tires: $15
Enter monthly cost on other maintenances: $14

Average monthly expense of automobile is $83.0. 

Average yearly expense of automobile is $996.0.
```